# Canvas draw path with dynamic paint color

Tags: android, canvas

I'm writing Android app for Arduino motor shield (Nucleo boards actually, but it does not matter), and I display the distance, measured by ultrasonic sonar sensor, as dots on the screen. On each update from Arduino (I send a packet with servo angle and sonar distance in cm), I draw a new Point. The problem is that sometimes for the same servo angle I have many sonar distances, and if I draw all of them, it gets messy.

**For each servo angle (X-axis), I want to draw only the latest measurement of sonar distance (Y-axis).**

Here is the plot with many points for the same servo angle.

[image]

Here is the code I use to draw all incoming points on a view's canvas: https://github.com/dizcza/FunduMotoJoystick/blob/b224e80d59fe11c0252dce7f78aca995f67a7d65/app/src/main/java/de/kai_morich/fundu_moto_joystick/SonarView.java

```java
public class SonarView extends View {
    private static final int POINT_RADIUS = 10;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private final Path mPath = new Path();

    public SonarView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    public void drawCircle(float x, float y) {
        mPath.addCircle(x, y, POINT_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CW);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mPath.reset();
    }
}
```

I called the topic "Canvas draw path with dynamic paint color" because if I can explicitly provide the color for each added item (circle) in the Path, I'd draw a white rectangle each time to cover the space below each new point.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method which will return paint object as

```
public Paint getCustomPaint(int color){
     Paint paint = new Paint();
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
     paint.setColor(color);
     return paint;
}
```

and call it as `canvas.drawPath(mPath, getCustomPaint(randomColor));`

**Edit:**

As per your requirements, you need to maintain an ArrayList(add it on top) as,

```
private ArrayList<Point> mPointsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Point> mWhitePointsList = new ArrayList<>();
private final Path mWhitePath = new Path();
```

then add a new method as,

```
private boolean isPointPresent(float x, float y) {
    Point lPoint = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (Point point : mPointsList){
        if(point.x == x){
            isFound = true;
            mPointsList.remove(point);
            mWhitePointsList.add(point);
        }
    }
    if(isFound) {
        mPointsList.add(lPoint);
        return true;
    }
    mPointsList.add(lPoint);
    return false;
}
```

also, make the changes in the drawCircle method as,

```
public void drawCircle(float x, float y) {
    if(isPointPresent(x, y)) {
        for(Point point : mWhitePointsList){
            mWhitePath.addCircle(point.x, point.y, POINT_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CW );
            mWhitePointsList.remove(point);
        }
    }
    mPath.addCircle(x, y, POINT_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CW);
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: but then you'd get a messy picture of dots with different colors

Comment: Yes, can you please explain exactly what you want?

Comment: if I've drawn point A (**20**, 30) and then receive a new point B (**20**, 40), I want to get rid of/cover the previous point A with a white rectangle. But if A was (**21**, 30) I want to keep it. Point B comes not necessarily after A. Between them I might receive many other points with different locations.

Comment: Such API would solve my problem: `mPath.addRect(x - POINT_RADIUS, getHeight(), x + POINT_RADIUS, 0, Path.Direction.CW, whitePaint);` and then `mPath.addCircle(x, y, POINT_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CW, blackPaint);`

Comment: Have you tried it by saving all points in arraylist but before adding new point just apply the condition. And then draw all points in arraylist(which you only want to show) so you don't have to add rectangle to cover the point. Right?

Comment: I thought about it. But then having a for loop will slow down the canvas rendering once the number of points becomes 100...1000.

Comment: Yes correct. But then how would you know if the previous point was nearby to the latest point received? You keeping track of all points?

Comment: Again, I can keep track of all points, find the index of the point with the same X-axis (or in some range) and remove it if any. It'd be just inefficient to draw the remaining array one by one.

Comment: Please check my edit and if it solves your problem vote and accept :) if not let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your attempts. However, you missed the key logic I put in the problem description - "For each servo angle (X-axis), I want to draw only the **latest** measurement of sonar distance (Y-axis)." Your implementation means that if we already have a point with the same X-axis, just ignore the update, which is opposite to logic I want. Your solution would work if after checking `if(!isPointPresent(x))` we call `mPath.remove(<point>)`. But Path object does not allow to do so.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that. I have updated again. well if you cant remove then I don't think it's possible as when you draw a line or rectangle it will change the color of full x-axis the points nearby will cut right?

Comment: White rect `mPath.addRect(x - POINT_RADIUS, getHeight(), x + POINT_RADIUS, 0, Path.Direction.CW)` might slightly cut nearby points, but this would be OK for me. It seems that your solution now requires having `mWhitePath` for each point candidate (is `mWhitePath` just a rect of width `2*POINT_RADIUS`?), which is equivalent to drawing circles in a for loop in the border case where many points have duplicates w.r.t. their X positions.

Comment: If `mWhitePath` is a singular object and your `onDraw` looks like this `canvas.drawPath(mWhitePath, mWhitePaint); canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);`, or vice verca, it does not solve either.

Comment: you need to add a line in onDraw() - canvas.drawPath(mWhitePath, mWhitePaint); its just lines having a stroke equivalent to circle diameter which will hide all older point on that same X-axis(drawing a vertical line). But it will also cut the circles. I am looking how can we get the exact location of older circle meanwhile you can try this.

Comment: Appending `canvas.drawPath(mWhitePath, mWhitePaint)` removes all points with duplicate X and leaves the points with unique X only, which is not the expected behavior. That is the first thing I did, actually. Then I realized it'll not work. The order of drawing white rectangles and black circles needs to be preserved. We cannot batch them in two separate paths.

Comment: thank you anyway. I let the question open so that someone maybe knows the solution. But thinking too much on one problem is not beneficial. I suggest you to try other questions on stackoverflow to gain a reputation.

Comment: Well, my last edit :( I totally agree. The two white and black paths are required as we cant set different paint to one path. try it. :)